# The Google Crawler is picking up the "It's 100% free, no registration required" phrase in its summary descriptions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Have a look at this search:

https://www.google.com/search?q=android+increase+volume+100%25

You will see entries like this:

[image]

I see why it's happening... It's part of the market-speak that appears on the page when a user visits the site for the first time.  But it has nothing to do with the question.

Is there a way to exclude that text from the Google crawler?

Comment: `<!--googleoff:index-->` before the div with the id of `blurb` and `<!--googleon:index-->` after the div. A rather messy solution (that only works for Google) but it should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Talk about unintended consequences...

We have gone with `<!--googleoff: snippet-->` on the question page - we agree, that text doesn't belong on the search result summary for questions.

This will be in the next build.

Oh, and thank you [Seth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/203389/seth) for pointing me at [this bit of google trivia](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing#pagepart) :)

Comment: This belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, snippet. Much better than index. Somehow I missed that one :P

Comment: Does that really work for normal Google search, as opposed to just the Google Search Appliance? The [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161599/how-can-i-prevent-google-engines-to-reference-links-and-previews-sections-of-my) I [found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497445/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-certain-parts-of-a-page) seem to claim it doesn't. I guess we'll soon find out, though. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Oh, I see what you are saying. Didn't realize that it was a Google Search Appliance / Google Mini thing. Not sure what we _will_ do if this isn't working.

Comment: To me `<-- googleoff: all-->` would be the correct choice. The marketing speak is still being indexed and therefor affecting search results even though it will no longer show the text in the snippet.

Comment: It might be possible to use http://schema.org metadata to give Google a hint about what the main content of the page is. (In particular, the WebPage schema has a mainContentOfPage property, and the Article schema has an articleBody property, either or both of which could make sense here.) However, if Google is actually making any use of these properties when choosing the snippet to display for "normal" web pages, they're sure being rather quiet about it.

Comment: I guess as this was a recent issue it's not a problem if I find more SO links with this "100% free..." text? If *not* the 4th result on Google for me when searching for "php match hash key number" points to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby with that advertising text in. Oddly, when searching for "why use symbols as hash keys in ruby" the description changes.

Comment: @Oded see also: [As it currently stands, this summary is not a good fit for google](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217913) `<!--googleoff: snippet-->` is for the appliance only. Maybe this is a case for ... shudder ...  the `content` property? This should work in all major browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/F3spu/

Comment: @Pëkka - yeah, it's been there long enough to show that it makes 0 difference :(