# When making a search on Google with the word 'POST' in it, many irrelevant results are returned

Tags: bug, search, google

I made the following search: https://www.google.tt/search?q=sharepoint+OpenPopUpPage+POST on Google and all of the SO results contained the following text on the search results page which indicates that they formed part of the data to be searched:

"By **posting** your answer, you agree to the privacy policy and terms of ..."

I was searching for using the OpenPopUpPage in SharePoint with HTTP POST. Shouldn't the Google crawler only index words in the title and body of the questions and answers and not irrelevant words like instructions about agreeing to the privacy policy?

Comment: @Mart Disagree - we could tell Google not to index that part. +1 to question

Comment: @MartijnPieters It hasn't ever been clear to me whether those options are supported by the main Google search engine, and not just in their enterprise "search appliance" system. (I've seem some websites, such as Quora use them IIRC, but they may have been misguided.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks: ah, indeed, and [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314111/avoid-google-to-crawl-part-of-a-page-googleoff-all-and-googleon-all) confirms your hunch. This won't work for the general web.

Comment: @Doorknob: **How** would you tell Google not to index those parts? There currently is no support to tell Google what to index and what to ignore.

Comment: @Mart Good point, I thought there was, but still, it's a problem, that might possibly have some solution (I don't know, there's must be some way...)

Comment: @Doorknob: Google can do as they please. There are some good guidelines on what Google uses to rank and what keywords where have move weight, but on the whole they keep their cards close to the chest to prevent gaming by SEO charlatans.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181203/the-google-crawler-is-picking-up-the-its-100-free-no-registration-required.  Summary: parts of the page can be excluded from the Google crawl.

Comment: @RobertHarvey actually that only works for internal google appliances, not their web crawler - documentation wasn't read closely enough first time around.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: that was just what Jeremy and I were discussing in the comments here; the Google Appliance comments don't work for the Google web crawlers; most likely because they don't want spammers to hide crappy content.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, Nick already clued me in (above).