# Will Stack Exchange traffic be affected as Google now shows an answer right on the search page

Tags: discussion, google, search-engine

I [searched the terms "JavaScript Closure"](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-f9eVImFGILV8gfa_IDQCQ&gws_rd=cr&fg=1#q=javascript+closure) in Google search and the very first result I found contains content from an answer posted on Stack Overflow. How this will impact Stack Exchange?

[image]

Comment: Google quotes from SO, and I think it is great that SO has become high quality enough to become a source of reference. When you click on the link, it actually leads back to SO, so I don't think there is any problem here.

Comment: Yeah I understand this.  But this also causes the traffic to SO gets reduced too!!  I guess online people are too lazy to click the link if they get the answer right in the search page.

Comment: Note that it is only an excerpt of the answer. People are more likely to click on the link rather than reading the short text there.

Comment: +1 If that is the case, then fine.  Just got curious.

Comment: for questions that are closed, showing answers instead makes a pretty good sense, see [As it currently stands, this summary is not a good fit for google](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217913/165773)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: Wow, that *is* a smart snippet (though maybe not the most descriptive). I wonder how they managed to select those 2 bullet points from [the last part of a loooong, second-best, non-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111111#111111).

Comment: I am missing the attribution, which is required I think. Isn't it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The link directly below the excerpt..

Comment: @ɥʇǝS, that link is not an attribution to the author of the answer (which, incidentally, is Community Wiki...)

Comment: @Arjan No it's not, and that could pose a problem..

Comment: As an aside, Stack Exchange team, [why does even W3Schools have a dropdown, but you don't](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wQuHv.png)? Are the URLs too long?

Comment: Hmmm, I have not found any other query that makes Google pop out a snippet like that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange encourages quality content which in turns require details and explanation (usually). I don't think that this Google feature will have any major negative impact on Stack Exchange, rather it may increase the traffic. Why, because the search engine tries to show an excerpt, encouraging new users to visit the site for complete information. In your example, the search page showed 300 characters, however that post contains approximately 11,600 characters.

Comment: I guess as long as it is just a snippet its fine.